# Collation error joining two tables of different DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have two data bases: db_A and db_B.

I'm trying to join one table from db_A with another table of db_B. Both of this tables have a column in common, id_card. So I'm trying something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM db_A.table_1
LEFT JOIN db_B.table_2
ON db_A.table_1.id_card = db_B.table_2.id_card
;
```

But when I run this code in SQL Server I get this error:

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 76 Cannot resolve the collation
> conflict between "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in
> the equal to operation.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: use [COLLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM db_A.table_1
LEFT JOIN db_B.table_2
ON db_A.table_1.id_card = db_B.table_2.id_card collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
```

Comment: Now I get the following error:

Msg 447, Level 16, State 0, Line 63
Expression type int is invalid for COLLATE clause.

Comment: your id_card fields are int or varchar?

Comment: @Miquel Then you wouldn't be getting the error you were before in the question. If an `int` and `varchar` are compared, then `varchar` would be implicitly converted to an `int` and there would be no collation error.

Comment: both must be varchar because both have numbers and letters, something like this: 34543H

Comment: If both are `varchar` values you won't get the error *"Expression type int is invalid for COLLATE clause."* @Miquel ... You are most certaainly hiding something from us here.

Comment: I'm not hiding anything. Now I have tried with another column to join both tables and again the same error, and in this case one is nvarchar(20) and the other one is varchar(15).